# jquery drop-event doesn't work in Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I use the jquery UI to enable drag & drop in my web application. Drag (`<div>` object) is possible in all browsers, but the drop event (into a `<td>` object) works just well in Firefox, but doesn't in Chrome and Safari.

This is my jquery code for the drop event:

```
$( ".dcell" ).droppable({
    greedy: true,
    accept: '.omba',
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
    ...
    }
});
```

CSS of the .dcell class:

```
.dcell {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    max-width: 50px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Can you see a reason why this code doesn't work in all browser?

Comment: Not enough code to help you. Also by making a jsfiddle you'll have more chance to bring people's attention on your issue.